# Querying many-to-many related data in .NET Core 2.x

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

These are sample entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCool { get; set; }
    public List<PersonCommunity> Communities { get; set; }
}

public class Community
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsPopular { get; set; }
    public List<PersonCommunity> People { get; set; }
}

public class PersonCommunity
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public Community Community { get; set; }
}
```

This is how they would be configured in ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

public DbSet<Community> Communities { get; set; }

public DbSet<PersonCommunity> PersonCommunities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonCommunity>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.PersonId, e.CommunityId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonCommunity>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Person)
        .WithMany(e => e.Communities)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.PersonId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonCommunity>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Community)
        .WithMany(e => e.People)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.CommunityId);
}
```

Now I want to take:

- Person
- By given Id

But:

- This person has to be Cool (IsCool = true)
- This person has to come from at least one Community which is not popular (IsPopular = false)

In all other cases, the query should return null, even if the person with a given Id exists in the database. So querying just `ctx.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id)` is out of the table.

I want to make it in the most optimised and efficient way, especially without loading any unnecessary data to the program's memory.

Tip: Originally, I have to query more than 2 mln users assigned to over 10k groups with a many-to-many relationship, by certain flags. And I can't just use SQL. It has to be EF Core.

I found plenty of similar questions that solve this problem either partly or either without meeting the efficiency requirement, which is critical here.

Comment: Everything except the last criteria is pretty standard filter. The last criteria is unclear -  *This person has to come from Community which is not popular (IsPopular = false)*. Person can come from 0..N communities, so what if (1) there are 0 communities (2) some person's community is `IsPoplular`, some is not? Most likely you are seeking for `p.Id == id &&  p.IsCool && p.Communities.Any(pc => !pc.Community.IsPopular))`, but the last condition is unclear.

Comment: As mentioned in question: 
(1) -> null
(2) -> Person, as it comes from (ok, I should have added that) at least one not Popular community.

Comment: Ok, "at least one meeting condition" is clear and is  == `Any(condtion)`. Again  pretty standard. What's the issue?

Comment: Could you help me out and try to compose entire query?

Comment: `ctx.People.FirstOrDefault(p => …)` with the criteria from the first comment.

Comment: And how do I load PersonCommunities to query Communities against IsPopular?

Comment: You don't need to load anything because the LINQ query is translated and executed as single SQL query. When used inside a query, navigation properties are translated to SQL joins.

Comment: Ok, so this is the actual thing, that I didn't know that I didn't know! :)

Comment: I see. Here is some explanation from the EF Core documentation - [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview) (and basically the whole [Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/) section). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the whole comment section under the question, I am posting the answer On behalf of **Ivan Stoev**.

Your query should be as follows:

```
Person person = _context.Peoples.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id && p.IsCool &&
                                 p.Communities.Any(pc => !pc.Community.IsPopular));
```